# What does (variable) mean in c++?

Tags: c++

In such case:

```
int x=0;
(x)=5;
```

Why is `(x)` a valid lvalue (and `decltype((x))` gives `int&`)?
What do parentheses mean here? Is there any similar situation?

Comment: You can also have `((((((((x)))))))) = ((((((5))))));`...

Comment: @0x5453 I agree. Thanks

Comment: As for what `(x)` means, see: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.paren

Comment: Someone was cleaning up their desk and found some spare parentheses.

Comment: Heh, I only just realised the accepted answer over there is one of mine. Actually read it 3 hours ago and everything.

Answer (score 1):

`decltype(x)` inspects the type of `x` entity. But when you put `x` inside parentheses, `decltype` have rules for deducing types for these expressions:

- if the value category of *expression* is xvalue, then decltype yields
  `T&&`;
- if the value category of *expression* is lvalue, then decltype yields
  `T&`;
- if the value category of *expression* is prvalue, then decltype yields
  `T`.

[source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).